# What is the opposite of "brute-force"?

Tags: terminology, antonyms, programming

In computer science especially, a brute-force algorithm is one that is naive and straightforward. It may succeed but only in a primitive way—trying all the obvious operations one by one. This wastes time and memory.

By contrast, the algorithms enabling our social media are quite *smart*. However, I do not know the terminology for it. What word, describes such thought-out approaches?

The word ideally takes both adjective and verb forms. The more widely applicable, the better. Does "smart" fit the bill?

Comment: The algorithm is efficient, sophisticated, advanced or optimised.

Comment: Thanks, but, out of these, only "optimise" works as a verb, too. Yet, when we use it as a verb, it doesn't mean what I want it to.

Comment: The opposite of "brute force" is "finesse".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you are speaking of *optimization algorithms* or *heuristic algorithms*.

There is a great variety of these techniques. For example:

> A **heuristic algorithm** is one that is designed to solve a problem in a faster and more efficient fashion than traditional methods by sacrificing optimality, accuracy, precision, or completeness for speed. In these problems, there is no known efficient way to find a solution quickly and accurately although solutions can be verified when given. Heuristics can produce a solution individually or be used to provide a good baseline and are supplemented with **optimization algorithms**. Heuristic algorithms are most often employed when approximate solutions are sufficient and exact solutions are necessarily computationally expensive

[Northwest university](https://optimization.mccormick.northwestern.edu/index.php/Heuristic_algorithms)

> The right choice of an **optimization algorithm** can be crucially important in finding the right solutions for a given optimization problem. There exist a diverse range of algorithms for optimization, including gradient-based algorithms, derivative-free algorithms and metaheuristics. Modern metaheuristic algorithms are often nature-inspired, and they are suitable for global optimization. In this chapter, we will briefly introduce **optimization algorithms** such as hill-climbing, trust-region method, simulated annealing, differential evolution, particle swarm optimization, harmony search, firefly algorithm and cuckoo search
>
> [Researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225448393_Optimization_Algorithms)

Comment: I think, though "heuristic algorithm" is the perfect terminology, it is not the perfect answer because it has no verb form I know of. "Optimise", too, just means "make optimal", not "do in an optimal way"... Is there a more general answer?

Comment: I saw that difficulty and could not resolve it to a verb. Please be free to "un-accept" the answer; I understand the difficulty but despite some searching I regretted that I could not find a suitable verbal term.

Comment: Your answer is good enough and introduced the new terminology to me; I am glad to accept it.

Comment: Heuristic isn't quite right.  For some problems, there can be non-brute force methods that give exactly the right answer every time.  Heuristic algorithms give a 'good enough' answer quickly.